# Retrieve the URLS of all articles in a wordpress/blogger blog.

Tags: wordpress, blogger

I would like to use a mechanism/API that can retrieve all the URLS of all articles. Ideally I would like to do it in many platforms, but it is adequate to start working with wordpress.org and blogspot.com.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Wordpress codex....

```
<ul>
<?php

// post_per_page value = number of total posts... 
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 9999999, 'offset'=> 1 );

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();?>

</ul>
```

In this example you need to use get_permalink(); instead of the_permalink to get URL as string..